# Allow to pause a long computation with a keystroke, and resume

Tags: python, windows, keyboard, interrupt

I'm doing a long (several days long) processing. I would like to be able to pause it at any moment and resume it:

```
while True:

    do_the_work()      # 100 millisec per call

    if keypressed():
        print "Processing paused. Please do another keypress to resume"
        raw_input()
```

What function should I use instead of the pseudo-code `keypressed()`?

Obviously `raw_input()` would not work here because it would wait *after each call* of `do_the_work()`.

Also using a

```
try: ... 
except KeyboardInterrupt: ...
```

wouln't work because it would exit the loop, instead of pausing / resuming. On the other hand, if the `try / except` is *inside* the loop, it would not exit the loop, but it would cause issues if it happens in the middle of `do_the_work()`.

Comment: You could write to a file and have your code check that file periodically.

Comment: `> using a try/except would exit the loop` not if it's inside the loop. It would likely be raised from the `do_the_work()` function and cause issues, though.

Comment: @PedrovonHertwig: yes indeed, if it's raised in the middle of the `do_the_work()`, it will cause issues. I edited OP to mention this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to ensure your `try/except` is *within* the `while` block.

**Sample:**

```
import time

total = 0
keep_going = True
while keep_going:
    try:
        total += 1
        print(total)
        time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        try:
            keep_going = input("Program is paused, type 'exit' to quit: ").lower() != 'exit'
        except KeyboardInterrupt:               
            break
print("Program has ended").
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
Program is paused, type 'exit' to quit: whatever
6
7
8
9
10
11
Program is paused, type 'exit' to quit: exit
Program Ending
```

Comment: Let's say `do_the_work()` lasts 1 second. If the user hits CTRL+C 0.5 sec after `do_the_work()` has begun, then this call will be interrupted and will never resume exactly there. The computation would resume at the next call of `do_the_work()`, so 0.5 seconds of work are lost.

Comment: Short of running it on a debugger console, I'm out of ideas, sorry.